# Cómo extraer un tag script (de gist, código embebido de github) contenido en XML

Tags: javascript, xml

Estoy guardando todo el contenido de un blog en archivos XML y luego por medio de javascript extraer el contenido de los archivos XML y ponerlos en el HTML de la página principal.

El problema es que los pedazos de código en github se comparten de esta forma:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
```

, donde se ejecuta un código javascript con `document.write(); // y ...otros`. Esto es un problema porque cuando después de ejecutarse la página y estar extrayendo información del XML esta no lo hace. Pienso que probablemente porque el javascript que se encarga de escribir el pedazo de código no puede ejecutarse mientras hay otro javascript escribiendo con `DomElement.innerHtml`

```javascript
document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML=xmlDoc.children[0].children[tag].innerHTML;
```

El XML es maso menos así:

```xml
 <subcontenido id="Deteccion de blobs_1"> 
 <h2 id="Tema-0">Deteccion de blobs</h2>
  <div>ho2la</div>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
  <div>hola</div>
 </subcontenido>
```

Imprime todo si no uso la etiqueta `<script>`, pero si la pongo solo se muestra hasta antes de la etiqueta.

Me gustaría saber porqué sucede esto y cómo podría utilizar el código embebido en el XML sin problemas.

Probé con estos recursos pero no me han funcionado: [How to include Javascript in xml-document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document)

Concretamente solo probé: `<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="external.js"></script>` y `<xmlns:script src="external.js"></script>` las otras no las entendí bien. La primera opción parece sí escribir en el HTML pero en bruto (pasivamente), ya que no se ejecuta el script y por lo tanto no escribe el 'snippet' de github.

**Edito:**  Agrego prueba comprobable. Los archivos son:

###### myXML.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <contenido> 
 <subcontenido id="Deteccion de blobs_1"> 
 <h2 id="Tema-0">Deteccion de blobs</h2>
  <div>ho2la</div>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
  <div>hola</div>
 </subcontenido>
  </contenido>
```

###### snippetJavascript.js

```javascript
  
  window.onload = function() {
      cargarContenido(0);
  };

    // Carga el contenido izquierdo y la informaciòn
    function cargarContenidoEntero(xml,tag) {
      debugger
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    
          document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML=xmlDoc.children[0].children[tag].innerHTML;
    
      } 
      var xmlDoc;
      function cargarContenido(tag) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cargarContenidoEntero(this,tag);
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","myXML.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
```

###### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>prueba1</h1>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
    <p>antes</p>
    <div id="Main"> </div>
    <script src="snippetJavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143801/dynamically-executing-a-script-tag-with-an-external-src-attribute-using-eval)
- [Executing  elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Pues yo lo acabo de probar con la etiqueta y lo imprime todo...

Comment: Gracias por probar @FranciscoJavier. Te muestra el snippet o código embebido? debería decir `asd` o `debe mostrar este texto`.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier He editado la pregunta agregando código mínimo funcional para comprobar, la idea es poder extraer el tag `<script>` empleando el XML. He probado poniéndolo directamente sin el XML y también me funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres utilizar HTML en un document XML, deberías utilizar XHTML, por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <contenido> 
 <subcontenido id="Deteccion de blobs_1"> 
 <h2 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="Tema-0">Deteccion de blobs</h2>
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">ho2la</div>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">hola</div>
 </subcontenido>
  </contenido>
```

o, para no tener que etiquetar cada elemento con el atributo `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, talvez introduzca un contenedor, por ejemplo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <contenido> 
 <subcontenido id="Deteccion de blobs_1"> 
 <section xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <h2 id="Tema-0">Deteccion de blobs</h2>
  <div>ho2la</div>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/A4lfr32/bc1cfdd3f24410d7b63a7a9dc0285103.js"></script>
  <div>hola</div>
 </section>
 </subcontenido>
  </contenido>
```

Entonces, en lugar de asignar a `innerHTML`, te recomendo utilizar DOM métodos como `document.getElementById("Main").appendChild(xmlDoc.children[0].children[tag].firstChildElement);`.

De esa manera, por lo menos, el navegador debe ejecutar el código JavaScript de cualquier elemento `script` que insertas.

Sin embargo, utilizar `document.write`, en mi opinión y en mi experiencia, solo funciona durante la creación inicial del documento HTML, si lo utilizas después, no inserta su contenido dentro de la página, sino borra la página y escribe una nueva.